# Sync Master and multiple client database (bi directional) - MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

Need some suggestions on how to achieve Master - Multiple Slave database - Bi directional.

we use MSSQL Server 2008, there is a head office and many branch offices and the database is installed in each of the office location ( head and also branch), the head office db will contain data from all the branch office's. the branch office thou will contain only its specific data.

So when syncing between HO and BO, need to send only certain data from same datatable (each table will have a condition through which the branch office specific data can be identified) from HO to BO. And ALL changes that happens on BO needs to be sent to HO. This generally happens twice a day.

Please suggest a suitable method. Some of the methods validated and not sure whether its the right method are
1) creating DML scripts from each table based on the data modifications done (like row_modified_date)

2) creating dml scripts for each table when the insert happens - on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve your goal is by using Merge Replication with Parameterized Row Filters.  Merge Replication is bi-directional by default and parameterized row filters will allow you to only replicate branch specific data to slaves (subscribers) while maintaining a full copy at the master (publisher).

Here are some links to get you started:

[Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx)

[Parameterized Row Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152478.aspx)

Comment: hi brandon...thanks for your comments...but my destination database will not be online at all, so is it possible in replicate to extract the changes as a file and send it across to my destination and merge it there ?